# Array out of bound exception?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
Map<Integer, Material> TestMap= new HashMap<Integer, Material>();

if (TestMap.get(index)!= null) {
    index++;
}
```

What will happen if `TestMap.get(index)` is `null`? Some say it will exit the code, some say it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: What loop? What is `TestMap`? a `HashMap`?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Where is your loop? If it's null then it wont enter your if condition.

Comment: Could you please provide your full source code?

Comment: `if(....)` is not a loop, its a control flow statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, for it's a `HashMap`. As per the documentation of the `get()` method of `HashMap`:

> public V get(Object key)
>
> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

So if the `HashMap` does not contain a value for `ìndex`, if will return null, no problem there.

EDIT

If your `HashMap` was a `List`, and you added 10 elements, and you called `get(25)` on the **`List`**, *then* you'd get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So to summarize

```
if (TestMap.get(index)!= null) {
    index++;
}
```

This piece of code doesn't throw any Exceptions (except when TestMap is null). If there's no value for the given key, `get()` returns null, and since you perform a null check, the if is not entered when the key doesnt exist in the map.